# Template not rendering in nestsj when using AuthGuard

Tags: node.js, jwt, nestjs

I am able to render template on browser without Authguard('jwt') but with it, i constantly get unauthorized error. Although if i run it on postman and pass my access token there, i am getting a response. This is my nestjs method, roles guard and jwt -

```
  @Render('upi')
  @Roles('customer')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  @ApiBearerAuth('access-token')
  @Get('dashboard')
  async renderDashboard(@Session() session: Record<string, any>) {
    console.log("sessionnnn", session.accessToken)
    return { token: session.accessToken }
  }
```

Role.guard

```
@Injectable()
export class RoleGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) { }

  matchRoles(roles: string[], userRole: string) {
    return roles.some((role) => role == userRole)
  }


  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const roles = this.reflector.get<string[]>('roles', context.getHandler());
    if (!roles) {
      return true;
    }
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const user = request.user;
    return this.matchRoles(roles, user.role);
  }
}
```

JWT strategy -

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    });
  }

  async validate(payload) {
    return payload;
  }
}
```

At the very first line of the method I have added a console.log statement but even before the code reaches that point 401 error is thrown. At first I thought it has to do something with access token handling in the frontend side. But on the frontend part access token is needed after the page is loaded as it is a payment page, so the api runs when i hit pay now button. So i guess before that there should be no need for access token. I am passing token in the frontend dynamically through return statement. I don't know if it made sense but i tried interchanging decorator's positioning , like placing @Render decorator before @UseGuard .I don't think i need to put my html too here but please let me know in comments if its needed here.

Comment: Can you provide the code for `@Roles` Decorator and `AuthGuard`